# Importing CRM Solution carries over the processes but some need to be re written

Tags: crm

Whenever I export a solution with all working process and business rules the imported solution shows this error in the process section. I have to then rewrite the entire process. This is rare though, the other exported processes come across fine.

[image: process fail]

is this down to the GUIDS of email accounts that are different between databases?

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when your workflow steps contains the create/send emails steps. And the TO, From, CC…  records you using that does not exists with same GUID in the environment you are importing it.

No need to rewrite the whole workflow again. You can just remove the old records which was selected in the send email steps then select the correspondence record in the new environment.